# Why my datetimepicker doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

My datetimepicker doesn't work, I don't know why, I just copied this code from bootstrap.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Birthdate:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
```

and JavaScript import:

```
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: whats the console say?

Comment: Did you follow the [install guide](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)? You're missing the bootstrap JavaScript file for one.

Comment: what do you mean sir @DaveChen thanks for your reply..

Comment: @Dagon i didn't check the console yet sir.

Comment: Can you provide your full source? I.e all the JavaScript includes. Take a look here ( http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/ ).

Comment: I don't think you need anything in the <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'> , try deleting everything inside it.

Comment: @DaveChen thats all my source..

<script type= "text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
</script>

Answer (score 1):

This plugin relies on [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which you don't appear to be using. Refer to the [Docs](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/) please.

## Minimal Requirements

1. jQuery
2. Moment.js
3. Bootstrap.js (transition and collapse are required if you're not
   using the full Bootstrap)
4. Bootstrap Datepicker script
5. Bootstrap CSS
6. Bootstrap Datepicker CSS
7. Locales: Moment's locale files are [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/master/locale)

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```